# backbone.js can't read from collection

Tags: backbone.js

Spent many hours and still can't figure that out. sampleData.json file contains the following json object.

```
[{name: "Tim", age: 5},{name: "Ida", age: 26},{name: "Rob", age: 55}]
```

Why this data is not available in the collection object?

```
var ListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/sampleData.json'
});



var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#file-list'),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render(); 
},
render: function() {
    $(this.collection.toJSON()).each(function(key, val) {
        console.log(val['name']);
    });
}
});

var list = new ListCollection();

list.fetch();

var listView = new ListView({
    collection: list
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`list.fetch()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) call is actually an AJAX call so there's no guarantee that it will have retrieve anything from the server when you try to use `this.collection` inside your view. The usual approach has two components:

1. Make your `render` smart enough to work with an empty collection.
2. Bind your `render` to the collection's `"reset"` event.

When you `fetch`, [a `"reset"` event is triggered](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch):

> When the model data returns from the server, the collection will *reset*.

So binding to the collection's `"reset"` event will trigger a call to your view's `render` when the server gets around to returning your data.

So you want something more like this:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#file-list'),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
        this.render(); 
    },
    render: function() {
        // Whatever really happens here should be able to handle an empty collection.
        this.collection.each(function(m) {
            console.log(m.get('name'));
        });
        return this; // This is conventional, it is expected of you that you do this.
    }
});
```

You'll notice that I've switched from jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to Underscore's [`each`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each);
Backbone collections have [various Underscore methods mixed in](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you might as well use them.

Backbone is an event based system so if you're having a problem, look to your event handling (or lack thereof) first.

Furthermore, this:

```
[ {name: "Tim", age: 5}, {name: "Ida", age: 26}, {name: "Rob", age: 55} ]
```

is JavaScript, not JSON, there is a slight difference. Your `sampleData.json` should look like this:

```
[{"name":"Tim","age":5},{"name":"Ida","age":26},{"name":"Rob","age":55}]
```

Take note of the quotes around the keys in the objects, JSON requires them.

Comment: I implemented the changes you suggested but there's still nothing showing in console :/

Comment: @marcin_koss: Have you checked your server logs? Is it returning anything? Have you added `success` and `error` callbacks to your `list.fetch()` call to see what's going on?

Comment: @marcin_koss: And does your JSON file contain exactly the text `[{name: "Tim", age: 5},{name: "Ida", age: 26},{name: "Rob", age: 55}]` or does it contain real JSON?

Comment: I added options to the fetch() as you suggested. This was printed to console in error callback `readyState 4
responseText "[ {name: "Tim", age: 5}, {name: "Ida", age: 26}, {name: "Rob", age: 55} ]"
status 200
statusText "OK"`

Comment: it seems it contains the text

Comment: I think you have a JSON format error on top of the possible async problem, please see my updated.

Comment: Excellent! AS you said the data was not formatted properly. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're passing the 'this.collection.toJSON()' to jquery's element selector. jQuery's each does not work like that - you need $.each(this.collection.toJSON()).

Second, and correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't simply use this.collection if you pass it in the constructor. You have to use this.options.collection.

Also, if you're using backbone you have underscore at your disposal. I'm not sure if this makes any difference, but underscore will use the native forEach if it exists (firefox, chrome) and will fall back for ie and other browsers that do not have that ability. I'm not sure that jquery does that. So, speed is definitely improved in those cases.

Comment: Regarding your second point, you *can* refer to `this.collection` when passing a collection to the view's constructor. From the documentation: "There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`."

Comment: Regarding your first point, `$(array).each(function(i, e) { ... })` works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kzGZG/

Comment: Well, I'm just striking out tonight in all fronts! :P

Comment: I tried console.log(this.collection) in the render method and it seems there's just no data in the collection (models is empty). I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: mu is right in his comment on your question - I completely overlooked the fact that your collection probably hasn't been fetched yet.